# VB Script - DB connectivity issue

Tags: qtp, adodb

Getting 'unspecified error' while executing the code below:

```
DBConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=  (DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
"(HOST="&strHost &")(PORT="& strPort &"))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME="& strServiceName &"))); uid="& strUID &";pwd="& strPwd &";"


If DBConn.State = "1" Then
  msgbox "connected"
Else
  msgbox "not connected"
End If

SQL = "select * from abc_tbl where abc_i in ('" & strValue & "')"  
DBRecordSet.Open SQL,DBConn 'GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE
```

This snippet is working when I try for many other tables, but for one table alone it's not working and throwing 'Unspecified Error'. Please point me where I'm going wrong in this. Thanks!

Comment: Try simplifying your code and remove everything that is not relevant to your question.  You're using 6 variables (strHost, strPort, strServiceName, strUID, strPwd, strValue) and that means we can't be certain what you're doing.  Eliminate all of that and re-post your most code.  Show the full connection string and full SQL query and it will be much cleaner and easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution for this issue,,, actually the issue was not with the code!

Yes, issue was with the table I tried to access. When I tried to execute the query with *, it had thrown 'Unspecified error'. But it worked when I tried to select some specific field directly.

Not sure what is the exact reason, why the query couldn't pick complete data from table using * query. But able to achieve if we try to retrieve field wise.

If anyone faced this type of issue and know the possible reason, please share the same in this thread. So that we'll know the reason too! :)

Comment: Again I got into this issue and resolved it in same way before... But really curious to know why the script fails for some tables? Is there any restriction to use * in certain tables?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. For some tables * is not working. Don't know why.